# Display MySQL database table data in VB 2010 textboxes

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I was able to display data from my MySQL table using this code: 
        datardr = cmd.ExecuteReader

```
    If datardr.HasRows Then
        datardr.Read()
        tb_lname.Text = datardr("SURNAME")
        tb_fname.Text = datardr("GIVEN")
        tb_mname.Text = datardr("MID")
        tb_mi.Text = datardr("MIDDLE")
        tb_app.Text = datardr("APPELLATION")
        tb_prefix.Text = datardr("PREFIX")
        tb_sex.Text = datardr("SEX")
        tb_status.Text = datardr("STATUS")
    End If
```

However, I noticed that it's not displaying all data coming from these fields. I can only view the SURNAME, GIVEN, MID and MIDDLE but the others are not displayed.. I have double checked my database fields and I'm sure that they're the same and without special characters or whitespaces.

Please help. Thanks!

Here is the exact code that I have => [VB2010 and MySQL Code](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=bmBXikXM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's another answer for you.

I think it's because of your SQL statement in **line 21**.
I assume you are selecting **ONE** record (am I right?), so that you can insert the resultant fields into the text boxes. And, you order the result with SURNAME. 
Did you double check whether there are already data inside the `masterlist` table? Especially check, if you already entered the data in every field in every row.

In line 30, you called `datardr.Read()` method, so the DataReader object `datardr` will read the first record line it encountered in the result of the sql statement.I think only the **four** fields of the first record, `SURNAME`, `GIVEN`, `MID` and `MIDDLE` has data values, and any other fields contain null values. So, you only got these FOUR values appeared inside the text boxes, and any other fields appeared to be blank.

I THINK IT MIGHT BE THE MAIN PROBLEM. Just check whether the data you wanted to be appeared already existed in the database table. OK!

And another suggestion. Don't you think you might need WHERE clause in your SQL statement? Well, you want to display only one record, don't you?

**WISH YOU BEST LUCK!!!   :-)**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, I have already checked my database and I'm positive that all fields contain values. In fact when I tried to do this via adding the MySQL database on the Data Sources, the records appeared on the DataGridView and also on the Textboxes..

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite understand what you meant on the previous comment. What happened when you add MySQL database on the Data source, and how the record appeared on the grid view and text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better check the sql statement that passed into the command object, `cmd`.
Maybe you didn't select the entire record with `select *`.

And, one more recommendation.
If `datardr` is the `DataReader`, I highly recommend you **NOT** to use it. It cause much problems than it serves. 
The more flexible approach is to use just the `DataTable`. 
The command object has `ExecuteNonQuery` method that returns the `DataTable` object. 
It is more flexible and much more easier to use than DataReader. Trust Me...! ;-)

Comment: I had an experience of spending an entire night selecting and reading data from DataReader object.

Comment: It takes just a short moment and with a few codes to select data from the DataTable, than the DataReader object.

Comment: sorry, but frankly I am quite a newbie on this and I don't know how to do that. I a going to paste my code in a few minutes and perhaps you can help me correct it. Thanks!